# how to get Http for my json file in chrome so i can fetch that link in my flutter app

Tags: json, api, http

I have my json file which contains some images. and I want to fetch that  json file in my flutter app through its http link so how I can make json file's http request anyone know then help me. I know how to fetch data in app after getting link. I just want to make this json file's http link. help if u know thx.

Comment: Please show what you have tried (your code, sample json data) and add a brief description
of your search efforts as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.